# After restructuring my node/express app, my static route to index.html will not work

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm wanting to server index.html as a default, as I'm using angular to handle client side routes.

Here's the structure of my app.

[image: app structure]

Here is app/app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router();

require('./config/db')(function(db) {
    require('./routes/routes')(app, router, null, db);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use('/', router);
    app.listen(config.port);
    console.log('Listening on port ' + config.port);
});
```

The only thing in ./routes/routes.js are server side routes. I'm really not sure what I did, but index.html used to load by default and then angular took care of the rest.

I'm new to node/express.

Error I keep getting is "Cannot get/"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can we have the router code? I suspect the index.html needs to be given a proper relative path in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

on the express configuration

in your route you need to have one to serve your root path

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    // Root routing
    var core = require('/controllers/core');
    app.route('/').get(core.index);
};
```

your server controller

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index'); //assuming that you are using some view engine.
};
```